# brun: error: unrecognized Arguments - Chialisp

Tags: invalid-argument

I am following a very basic chialisp tutorial to create a very basic (insecure) smart contract on the chia blockchain.

The chialisp code behind is:

```
(mod (
        password_hash
        password
        receive_puzzlehash
        transaction_amount
    )
    (if (= (sha256 password) password_hash)
        ; true - password was correct
        (list
            (list CREATE_COIN receive_puzzlehash transaction_amount)
        )
        ; false - password was incorrect
        (x "Bad password")
    )
)
```

At this stage it is still mostly learning the syntax.
I compile the code into low level code as such:

```
(venv) Y:\Chialisp\Legacycoin Tutorialcoin>cdv clsp build passwordprotect.clsp
Beginning compilation of passwordprotect.clsp...
...Compilation finished

(venv) Y:\Chialisp\Legacycoin Tutorialcoin>run passwordprotect.clsp
(a (i (= (sha256 5) 2) (q 4 (c (q . "CREATE_COIN") (c 11 (c 23 ()))) ()) (q 8 (q . "Bad password"))) 1)
```

Then I try to execute the puzzlehash / program:

```
(venv) Y:\Chialisp\Legacycoin Tutorialcoin>brun "(a (i (= (sha256 5) 2) (q 4 (c (q . "CREATE_COIN") (c 11 (c 23 ()))) ()) (q 8 (q . "Bad password"))) 1)" "(0x9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08 test 0xa11ce 1000)"
usage: brun [-h] [--strict] [-x] [-s STAGE] [-v] [-t] [-c] [--time] [-m MAX_COST] [-d] [--quiet] [-y SYMBOL_TABLE] [-n] [--backend BACKEND] [-i INCLUDE] path_or_code [env]
brun: error: unrecognized arguments: (0x9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08 test 0xa11ce 1000)

(venv) Y:\Chialisp\Legacycoin Tutorialcoin>
```

What does the unrecognized arguments error mean? Is there an issue with my input format? Is there an error to compile one of the arguments?
I cannot see any diference from the Tutorial except I am using double quotes (on windows cmd) and the tutorial (on linux) uses single quotes. Using single quotes did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Error:

1. Do not use CMD for executing chialisp code. Although it works to some degree, plenty of stuff does not.
   [image]
2. Double quoting inside of each other cancles out. In the above screenshot, this is not visible but powershell with syntax highlighting makes this quite obvious:
   [image]

### Solution:

1. Use PowerShell instead on windows.
   [image]
2. Use single quotes for encapsulation such as:

```
'(a (q 2 (i (= (sha256 11) 5) (q 4 (c 2 (c 23 (c 47 ()))) ()) (q 8 (q . "Bad password"))) 1) (c (q . 51) 1))'
```

**`IMPORTANT:`** windows powershell has inverse quoting standards from linux. This means on Windows, the outer quotes need to be inversed:

```
"(a (i (= (sha256 5) 2) (q 4 (c (q . 'CREATE_COIN') (c 11 (c 23 ()))) ()) (q 8 (q . 'Bad password'))) 1)"
```